Chi-square goodness of fit test Python SciPy
in the SciPy Manual v1.12.0 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html there is an example for the Chi-square goodness of fit test:
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

x = stats.t.rvs(10, size=1000)
quantiles = [0.0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1-0.10, 1-0.05, 1-0.01, 1.0]
crit = stats.t.ppf(quantiles, 10)
crit
# array([       -inf, -2.76376946, -1.81246112, -1.37218364,  1.37218364,
#         1.81246112,  2.76376946,         inf])
n_sample = x.size
freqcount = np.histogram(x, bins=crit)[0]
tprob = np.diff(quantiles)
nprob = np.diff(stats.norm.cdf(crit))
tch, tpval = stats.chisquare(freqcount, tprob*n_sample)
nch, npval = stats.chisquare(freqcount, nprob*n_sample)
print('chisquare for t:      chi2 = %6.2f pvalue = %6.4f' % (tch, tpval))
# chisquare for t:      chi2 =  2.30 pvalue = 0.8901  # random
print('chisquare for normal: chi2 = %6.2f pvalue = %6.4f' % (nch, npval))
# chisquare for normal: chi2 = 64.60 pvalue = 0.0000  # random

My question is, why do they use df=10 in "crit = stats.t.ppf(quantiles, 10)", and how to determine a proper value for df?
Many thanks in advance.
It's just a question regarding general understanding.

If you look at the documentation for scipy.stats.t.rvs
rvs(df, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)

And in your example, they already set df to be 10 so it is just carried over for the ppf function.
An alternative way to figure out an "ideal" degrees of freedom is to run
stats.t.fit(x)

